# sudoers syntax different for server vs desktop?

Tags: 12.04, sudo, syntax

Is there a difference in syntax between the server and desktop ubuntu 12.04 distro? If so could I get help rewriting this line to be valid for the desktop env?

```
user1 ant =(user1) NOPASSWD: ~/progs/tool/start.sh
```

the start.sh script should be executable from an ant target initiated by user1...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no syntax difference.

Edit with `sudo visudo` and you'll get some syntax checking.